# Multiple if statements efficiency

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

Let's say I have `boolean show` and difficult method `public boolean isArraySorted( )`.
I want to know how if statement works, and if checking order means anything. Basicly what I want to is `if( !show && isArraySorted( ) )` is faster than `if( isArraySorted( ) && !show )`.

As far as I know statements are checked one after another until one fails, **right** ? So keeping this in mind `if( !show && isArraySorted( ) )` should be faster ( at least slightly ). Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Logical operator short circuiting is happening with `&&`. And yes, the order matters. Therefore, you also see thousands of examples such that `if (objVariable != null && objVariable.doSomething() )`.

Comment: The more **boldface** you use in your writing, the harder it is to read, just FWIW.

Comment: Hint for the net time: why don't you implement two methods that log to the console that they've been called and return a boolean value. Then call them two combinations of such an expression and see what's being logged. Protip: use a debugger and step into those methods, don't struggle writing console statements. Further: your question is not limited to `if` statements, the same applies for `bool result = a || b;`. Finally: for or-statements if the lefthandside is true, there's no need to evaluate the righthandside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basicly what I want to is `if( !show && isArraySorted( ) )` is faster than `if( isArraySorted( ) && !show )`.

Let's leave speed off to the side. `if( !show && isArraySorted( ) )` won't call `isArraySorted` if `show` is `true`, and will if it's `false`. (Because you're using `!show`, otherwise it would be the other way around.)

> As far as I know statements are checked one after another until one fails, right ?

Sort of, yes. The logical operators (`&&` and `||`) are *short-circuited*. That means that they evaluate their left-hand operand and, if that operand is enough that they know their result, they don't evaluate the right-hand operand. So for `&&`, if the left-hand is `false`, there's no need to evaluate the right-hand. For `||`, if the left-hand is `true`, there's no need to evaluate the right-hand.

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted to know!